# Run java file from another java file in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, runtime.exec

I want to run "ClassA" from "RunJavaFromJava" in netbeans here is my code:

let me tell you first it is working fine without netbeans but I want it through netbeans

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is ClassA");
    }
}




public class RunJavaFromJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java ClassA");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it through Netbeans?

Comment: It shows nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by

Calling `ClassA.main()` from RunJavaFromJava instead of using Process

```
    package runjavafromjava;

    public class RunJavaFromJava {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ClassA.main(null);
           }

    }


   //If you still want to use Process

    Process p ;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java ClassA")
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
             System.out.println(br.readLine());
}

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your above code the program doesn't o/p anything as the o/p of the process is not redirected.
 PS: Make sure the .class file is in the the class path

Comment: Should be `ClassA.main(null)` or something.  You need a parameter.

Comment: @Steve Smith Thanks..updated my answer, As I normally use var args in main I did not think of using null

Comment: I want it through Process

Comment: through Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: I want it through Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: @AmithPradhan please look at the answer i am using getRuntime.exec only.please look at the comment in the code..it has both the ways